# tuple as key to a dictionary says: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have this function in python:

```
def initialize(s,cfg):
    pi={},
    for i,w in enumerate(s):
        j=i+1
        for X,rhs in cfg.items():
            if rhs.has_key(w):
                print (j,j,X),rhs[w]
                pi[(j,j,X)]=rhs[w]
    return pi
```

and when run I get

```
    pi[(j,j,X)]=rhs[w]
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

The print above it returns `(1, 1, 'DT') 1.0`

I must be missing something, but as far as I can see I am not trying to mutate the tuple. Why do I get that error?

At one point I thought that it may be due to j and X being pointed to and tried to create a new tuple, but that didn't work. I also tried this on the shell:

```
>>> pi={}
>>> X="DT"
>>> j=1
>>> t=(j,j,X)
>>> pi[t]=1.0
>>> pi
{(1, 1, 'DT'): 1.0}
```

and as you can see, it all works. Any ideas on why do I get the `tuple does not support item assignment error` in my function, but not on the shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a trailing comma on this line:

```
pi={},
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
pi = ({},)
```

In other words, pi is a tuple.

Comment: Indeed. If you think a variable is a dict, and Python is telling you it's a tuple, the first thing to do is to *assume Python is correct* and figure out why your variable is a tuple instead of a dictionary.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `dict.has_key` has been removed in Python 3.x, and it's been best practice to use `if w in rhs` for many a year now...